# Visual Studio 2017 Dataset Designer not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2017

[image]

Hi Everyone
 I Installed Visual Studio 2017 on Newly Installed PC Windows 10 Pro But 
**DataSet Designer with old Framework project Before 4.6 .NET Version are not Opening**  Plz Help if any troubleshooting is there . Thanks

Comment: look at this link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40339/vs2017-aspnet-dataset-designer-not-working.html

Answer (score 1):

Restart your computer, it will upgrade project. if not your problem solution may be

- Update visual studio 2017 with requird packages.

Comment: Thanks for  responding saleem but done updates and restarts type things